# Remove bookmark star button from address bar

Tags: google-chrome

While searching for an answer I saw multiple threads about removing the bookmarks bar but what I'm looking for is how to remove the start icon inside the address bar located in the right side. The "Bookmark this page" button.

There may exist other older related questions with the answer of those times (probably saying that there's no way to do so) but hopefully the tecnology has advanced enough to allow such greatness customization without any third party software, add-on, extension, workaround, or anything of that kind.

Here's an image to clarify:

[image: Sorry for the sarcasm]